# Pointing 2 Domain Names to 2 Websites hosted on 1 Windows VPS with 1 IP

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, vps, nameserver, windows-server-2012

I have the following:

**A Softsys Windows 2012 unmanaged VPS running IIS 8 with 2 websites:** 
 - inetpub/wwwroot/WebsiteA with bindings 123.xxx.xxx.xxx:8001 
 - inetpub/wwwroot/WebsiteB with bindings 123.xxx.xxx.xxx:8002

**2 Domain Names:**
 - name1.com and
 - name2.com
 - registered at GoDaddy

How do I get http://name1.com to redirect to 123.xxx.xxx.xxx:8001 and http://name2.com to 123.xxx.xxx.xxx:8002 without using port numbers in the URL?

Although I know lot more about DNS, A records and what not - I seem unable to find and simple step by step solution to this- what I would imagine - crucial/common question on Google.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you run all the websites on port 80 and as long as you've added the relevant domain names into the configuration on each website in IIS, it'll know which site to serve based on the web address entered by the user.

Comment: This seems very different to what I have understood until now...  Do you thus mean that if I setup both WebsiteA and WebsiteB with bindings on port 80; and with both http://name1.com and http://name2.com's  "A Records" pointing to 123.xxx.xxx.xxx; that somehow IIS will correctly render the the 2 specific websites for the URL names entered!?

Comment: Exactly, except there is no "somehow", you will have to bind each Host name to appropriate IIS web site: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Working now thanks, Host Headers in IIS was indeed the thing I was looking for.